# How do I introduce the or clause into arrow functions?

Tags: javascript

In the following setup, I'm requesting for a certain action to take place if I so happen to find DOM elements that have a specific textContent value...

```js
    //CHECKING TO MAKE SURE IM ON THE RIGHT PAGE
    var mTarget = document.querySelector(".mCustomPage #my-table-listing");

    if (mTarget) {
    //LETS GET ALL THE TABLE TD ELEMENTS THAT HAVE A TEXT VALUE OF "VALUE A"
    var mItems = Array.from(mTarget.querySelectorAll("td font")).find((el) => el.textContent === "ValueA");

        //IF ANY OF THEM EXIST...
        if (mItems) {
            //DO SOME ACTION...
            mItems.closest("tr").classList.add("d-none");
        }
     }
```

...but how should I think about expanding my logic if I want "mItems" to not only check against "ValueA", but if el.textContent "*could also be*" "ValueB", or "ValueC", etc..?

I know the easy way is to just keep creating multiple variables. But whats the fun in that when learning how to advance a single arrow function to do this.

Many thanks on any tips!

Comment: Keep a set/array of valid values, then do (pseudo) `values.contains(el)`

Comment: I don't know how to do that yet - do you have a guide?

Comment: There are many ways to check [if an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript) (an array being `[...]`). There's also `Set` which has a `contains` function, but no native syntax for declaring them outside of `new Set`. You should really learn more about primitives/functions/OOP before doing things like lambda expressions (and imo, javascript). There's a bit of a perl-ism in javascript which is that there are many ways to do the same thing, which leads to everyone doing things different (thus hard to learn/read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `includes()`. The code below uses optional chaining `?.` so you don't need to test if the match succeeds using an `if` statement.

```js
let mTarget = document.querySelector(".mCustomPage #my-table-listing");
let matches = ['ValueA', 'ValueB', 'ValueC']
     
[...mTarget.querySelectorAll("td font")]
  .find(el => matches.includes(el.textContent))
  ?.closest('tr').classList.add('d-none')
```